# How to check arithmetic sequence

Tags: java

I want to write a program that looks for three numbers in array that gives an arithmetic sequence of length three - three numbers a,b and c form an arithmetic sequence of length 3 if: b-a = c-b.

The problem is that he code doesn't print "yes" even when it should, it never get into the command if. I guess I have a problem when writing the math command for b-a = c-b.

```
public static void main (String[] args)  {
    int [] a = new int [args.length - 1];W
    for (int i = 0; i<a.length; i++) {
       a[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i+1]);
     }
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 2; i++) {
       for (int j = i+1; j < a.length - 1; j++) {
          int b = a[i];
          for (int k = j + 1; k < a.length; k++) {
             int c = a[k];
             if (b - a[i] == c - b) {
               System.out.println("yes");
                break;
             }
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
```

Comment: And what is the issue? What happens when you run it? Can you provide some sample input and output? Also, `args[i+1]` will give `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` when `i` is `a.length - 1`.

Comment: Is this a homework ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

---

Changes:

1. First sort the array
2. When you break from the inner most loop, you
       must also break from all the outer loops (check code below)

---

```
Arrays.sort(a);

outerLoop:
for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 2; i++) {

    for(int j = i+1; j < a.length - 1; j++){

        for(int k = j+1; k < a.length; k++){

            if(a[j] - a[i] == a[k] - a[j]){
                System.out.println("yes");
                break outerLoop;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Update:
You are missing the first element of the array because of this code:

```
int [] a = new int [args.length - 1]
for (int i = 0; i<a.length; i++) {
       a[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i+1]);
     }
```

Change it to:

```
int [] a = new int [args.length]
for (int i = 0; i<a.length; i++) {
       a[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
     }
```

Comment: "2 3 4 6" would give "yes" when it is no unless you're making your program for only three numbers :3

Comment: It should be yes, as he is looking for 3 numbers that make arthemetic sequence.

Comment: Ah sorry, I thought she was looking for the whole array to be an arithmetic sequence

Comment: Thank you. There is a still a little problem. For the input: 2,3,4,6, I print every letter in the loop in order to see what it checks: " for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 2; i++) {
           System.out.println(a[i+1]);
           System.out.println(a[i]);
           System.out.println(a[i+2]);"  and it brings back : "'4,3,6". Why the 2 is missing?

Comment: So what is the problem? what did you get when you print each number?

Comment: I get 3,4,6 without 2.

Comment: Oh I see. now I understand where I was wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int [] a =new int [new Integer(args.length)];
        for (int i = 0; i<a.length; i++) {
               a[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
        }

        for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++){

        if(j+2<a.length){           
        if(a[j+1]-a[j] ==a[j+2] - a[j+1])
        System.out.println("Yes........." +a[j] +""+ a[j+1] +"" +a[j+2]);

        }
    }
}
```

tested with 2 3 4 6(2 3 4 is sequence) and 1 3 5 7 (1 3 5 and 3 5 7 are sequence)